# using rxjs to loop over array of numbers and calling api in groups of 3 calls with mergeAll(), need to retry each individual one if error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of numbers, that represent the 'pageNumber={val}' to tack on to the end of an api call that needs to run for each number. There could be 2 calls, or there could be 30 calls, so I am grouping the calls into 3 at a time with mergeAll(3) to redue bottleneck. Once all the calls have succeeded, I am finishing the process (converting to a csv file for download). The issue I am having is that I need to retry a SINGLE api call at least 3 times if it fails, before stopping the whole process.
Here is the first part, that is making the calls:
( pages looks like: [1,2,3,4,5,6] )

```
    const queue$ = from(pages)
       pipe(
        retry(3), <-- tried this (does nothing)
        map(p => this.apiService.getAll<any>(`${url}${query}&pageNumber=${p}`)
        ),
        retryWhen(errors => { <-- tried this (does nothing)
          return errors;
        }),
        take(3), <-- tried this  (does nothing)
        mergeAll(3)
      )
    ;
```

Once each is done, I push into the results, and then upon complete, go finish downloading:

````
    queue$
      .pipe(
        retry(3), <-- this makes each group of 3 retry, which is not what I want
        tap(resp => {
          // trigger progress bar
          this.csvDownloadingService.setDownloadProgress(percentToShow);
          percentToShow += percentMultiplier;
          results.push(resp);
        }),
        tap({
          complete: () => this.finishDownload(results, whichReport),
          error: (e) => this.finishDownload([], whichReport, e)
        })
      )
      .subscribe()
    ;
```
I can get each group of 3 to retry if any one of them fails, but that is not what I need. I need a single get to retry of the group if it fails. 
Thank you!
````

Comment: Both answers should be marked as the solution. Adding the retry to the service call was the solution, and having it laid out in code was helpful. Thanks you to both!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to keep your approach about this problem.
try to define retry to single request like this

```
// this way retry run for every single request , not for mergeAll operator
 singleRequest = (page) => {
  return this.apiService.getAll<any>(`${url}${query}&pageNumber=${page}`)
        .pipe(
        retry(3)
     )
} 

// and then use this arrow function in your code 

const queue$ = from(pages)
       pipe(
        map(p => singleRequest(p)),
        mergeAll(3)
      )


queue$
      .pipe(
         tap(resp => {
          // trigger progress bar
          this.csvDownloadingService.setDownloadProgress(percentToShow);
          percentToShow += percentMultiplier;
          results.push(resp);
        }),
        tap({
          complete: () => this.finishDownload(results, whichReport),
          error: (e) => this.finishDownload([], whichReport, e)
        })
      )
      .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the `retry(3)` on your service call Observable. I'd advise using the `mergeMap(() => obs$, 3)` implementation to limit your concurrent requests to 3 rather than `mergeAll`.

Comment: Thank you. This has been a learning adventure with rxJS for sure. Could you tell me the advantage of mergeMap over mergeAll for grouping my requests?

Comment: If you use `mergeMap`, you can remove the `map`. You're currently transforming each emission into an Observable and then subscribing to them. Using mergeMap does this in a single operator.